# UnityScript - How To Loop Through Public Properties of A Class

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have the following script in `UnityScript`, which is called `JavaScript` in Unity Editor but is not quite the same especially for looping through objects.

```
public class UpgradeProfile extends MonoBehaviour {

    public var brakeSpeed : float = 0;
    public var jumpForce  : float = 0;
    public var maxJumps : int = 1;

};
```

How can I loop through all the properties of this class and, for example, log the values or sum them with the values of another member of the same class?

**Note:**  UnityScript is not JavaScript *or* C# so answers relating to those languages do not answer this question.

Comment: Whoever is attempting to remove the ienumerable tag via an edit - you are incorrect. It could be a relevant tag in UnityScript - it is not limited to C#.

Comment: Author, you are also incorrect. UnityScript gets cross translated to Boo, which then gets cross translated to C#, which then actually gets compiled to the target platform. I haven't spent much time in UnityScript, but I'd be surprised if there's no way to utilize a C# answer within your UnityScript code. I write Unity code in Boo, personally.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare where do you get the idea from that UnityScript gets cross-translated to Boo and then C#? Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @Bart - I can't find the source right now but I remember a few years ago that one of the developers that work on Unity said the only reason Boo was supported was so that UnityScript could be cross-translated to it. Boo compiles down to the same runtime that the C# code does (Mono, right?)

Comment: Yup, Mono indeed. That would go some way into explaining why Boo is phased out but not forgotten completely just yet @ArtOfWarfare. Interesting. I never knew that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me to get the properites and values.

```
#pragma strict

public var test1 = 10;
public var test2 = 11;

function Start () 
{

    for(var property in this.GetType().GetFields()) 
    {
        Debug.Log("Name: " + property.Name + " Value: " + property.GetValue(this));
    }

}
```

And this prints out

```
Name: test1 Value: 10
Name: test2 Value: 11
```

And if you want to do this with another component, replace `this` with a `component` instead

Comment: This answer fully worked even for a more complex class, thank you very much.